# $E$ is compact if and only if X is compact and $q$ is a finite-sheeted covering

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $q:E\to X$ be a covering map. Then $E$ is compact if and only if X is compact and $q$ is a finite-sheeted covering.

My question is regarding the $"\implies"$ direction:
If $E$ is compact, then $X$ is compact since $q$ is a continuous surjection. Now let $x\in X$, and let $V$ be an evenly covered nbhd of $x$. Then $q^{-1}(V) = \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ where each $U_{\alpha}$ is open and connected. In particular $q^{-1}( \{x\} )$ is closed and thus compact. Then since $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ is an open cover of $q^{-1}( \{x\} )$, it must contain a finite subcover, which proves that $q$ is finite-sheeted. 
Is this logic correct?

Comment: If the choice of $X$ is not restricted $\{x\}$ may not be closed. Every point in a space is closed iff it is T1.

Comment: Normally $V$ is not assumed to be connected in the definition of a covering. It seems somewhat restrictive, and in this case irrelevant even.

Comment: This is correct if $X$ is T1, but not otherwise.

Comment: Sorry what is T1?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space